# What is the use of glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW) in resize()?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

```
static void resize(int width, int height)
{
   const float ar = (float) width / (float) height;

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity() ;
```

}

viewport and projection matrix got resized,when we change the window size ,but what is the use of calling GL_MODELVIEW inside resize function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glMatrixMode` sets current matrix type. All matrix-modifying operations (`glLoadIdentity`, `glLoadMatrix`, `glTranslatef`, ...) using current matrix.

Given code sets current matrix type to projection, modifies it, then sets current matrix to modelview so subsequent code (outside of this function) will modify modelview and not projection, and resets it to identity matrix (which is probably unnecessary, depending on draw function).

Comment: If your drawing code aware that matrix type isn't promised to be modelview and sets it manually, then yes.

Comment: The `glLoadIdentity()` call is redundant at best. If the draw function already resets the matrix to identity at the end, it's unnecessary. If there's normally a non-identity matrix on the modelview stack that the draw function uses, this will wipe it out. It's very common to set up the view matrix on the modelview stack once, and then leave it there. So IMHO, this is bad code.

Comment: @RetoKoradi on LoadIdentity I'm very likely to agree, but resetting matrix type back to modelview is welcome. But anyway, even half-modern GL don't have matrix functions anymore, so all this is deprecated and may be used for education purpose only...